# The noip2 (no-ip.com) package was deleted from the repository, now what?

Tags: repository

The No-IP websites still provides Ubuntu users with an installation guide that uses Aptitude, but the package [noip2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/noip2/2.1.9-3) has been deleted from the repository.

Is there a way to find out why a given package got deleted from the repository?

Is it possible that it will come back or has to be resubmitted by No-IP.com?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

easy just compile follow this guide to compile Linux Dynamic Update Client (DUC) on your Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

**How to install No-IP Linux Dynamic Update Client (DUC) on your Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.**

You will be able to install No-IP.com’s DUC in just a few minutes with terminal. Once you have opened up your terminal window you will need to login as the “root” user. You can become the root user from the command line by entering "sudo -s" followed by the root password on your machine.

```
cd /usr/local/src/
wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
tar xf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
cd noip-2.1.9-1/
make install
```

You will then be prompted to login with your No-IP.com account username and password.

If you get "make not found" or "missing gcc" then you do not have the gcc compiler tools on your machine. You will need to install these in order to proceed.

Source and more information to how to configure the client -> [HERE](http://support.no-ip.com/customer/portal/articles/363247-installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I found it like 10 minutes after I asked.

Comment: Will that auto load on each reboot or do I have to run `/usr/local/bin/noip2` every boot manually?

Comment: @ppumkin Read the README file in the no-ip-2.1.9 folder for instructions on how to make the client run at startup.

Answer (score 19):

### Security issues with noip2

The removal of the noip2 Dynamic Update Client (DUC) from the repository is explained in
[Debian bug #653957](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=653957).
One of the problems was a security issue, described in
[Debian bug #601229](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=601229).

In addition to those problems, noip2 (at least version 2.1.9) sends your password unencrypted over the internet, which is a particularly bad thing if your No-IP account contains MX records (e-mail domain names), IMAP accounts, or any other important services.

If you want to continue to use the noip2 client, it could be a good idea to use a sub-account, i.e. a group with password (this feature is a pay-service). This way, the password only gives access to updating the specified hosts and not full access to your entire No-IP account.

#### Use ddclient instead

A good alternative to noip2 is ddclient. It can be found in the repository and it can use secure connections. How to set up ddclient for No-IP is described here:

[How can I set up a Dynamic DNS fetching service on Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73048/how-can-i-set-up-a-dynamic-dns-fetching-service-on-ubuntu-server)

Comment: +1, the only answer that actually explains *why* `noip2` package was removed from the repos, instead of copy-and-paste the instructions to install from sources.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to have been deleted from repositories. This works for me:

```
wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
```

Uncompress the file. You can do this from the command-line if you wish:

```
tar xzvf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
```

Then run these commands:

```
make
sudo make install
sudo vi /etc/rc.local
```

That last command opens the file `/etc/rc.local` in the command-line text editor `vi`. If you're not comfortable with `vi`, you may want to use `nano` instead. In the file, add this line, making sure it appears before any instance of `exit 0:`:

```
/usr/local/bin/noip2
```

Save the file and quit the text editor.

Answer (score 5):

i'm really new to the linux os and i was having the same problem with with no-ip on ubuntu server 12.4
after a bit of digging i found a solution.

you need to install the gcc and g++ compilers, This will also install GNU make.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
gcc -v
make -v
```

to install No-IP Linux Dynamic Update Client Ubuntu 12.04

```
cd /usr/local/src/
wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
tar xf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
cd noip-2.1.9-1/
sudo make install
```

you should get asked for your email add and password

just enter them and bobs your teapot

this worked for me and i'm up and running;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just download the deb and install it?

> wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/26258014/noip2_2.1.9-3_amd64.deb
>
> sudo dpkg -i noip2_2.1.9-3_amd64.deb

Comment: This, in my opinion, would be the best solution. Why fiddle with compiling stuff when you can avoid it? This also makes for easy uninstall, when required.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct URL address is 
http://www.noip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz.

Try the following commands:

```
sudo wget http://www.noip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
sudo tar xf wget noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
```