# How do I install no-ip DUC on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt

I want to install no-ip DUC on ubuntu 14.04. When I run the following command(as the [guide](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu/) says)

`sudo apt-get install noip2`

I get the following error.

`E: Unable to locate package noip2`

How can I fix this and how can I install no-ip DUC on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: It has been removed from Ubuntu Repository. Refer [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/184712/299084) to install it.

Answer (score 8):

no-ip Ubuntu 14.04

`sudo apt-get install noip2`

could not found the package in a repository. So, to install `noip2` you have to:

```
sudo -i
cd /usr/local/src/
wget http://www.noip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
tar xf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
cd noip-2.1.9-1/
make install
rm /usr/local/src/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
```

To config defaults noip2 with capital C

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/noip2 -C
```

To change time interval noip2 with capital U

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/noip2 -U 120
```

To restart

```
sudo /usr/local/src/noip-2.1.9-1/debian.noip2.sh restart
```

Comment: mv /usr/local/src/noip-2.1.9-1/debian.noip2.sh /etc/init.d/
   chmod +x /etc/init.d/debian.noip2.sh