# No-IP DUC on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, server

So I have a Ubuntu Server running 16.04 that I'd like to get the no-ip.com Dynamic Update Client (DUC) installed on and starting automatically.

I did find some instructions ([Official No-IP](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu/) & [AskUbuntu Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491124/how-do-i-install-no-ip-duc-on-ubuntu-14-04)) and went through the install, but I can't seem to get it to run at boot. Nor does the system seem to recognize that it's installed.

Appreciate any and all attempts at help. :)

EDIT: Found this link that worked perfectly:
https://www.andreagrandi.it/2014/09/02/configuring-ddclient-to-update-your-dynamic-dns-at-noip-com/

Comment: I found [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS) a really good guide when i set this up on my system.

Comment: Per @alban, I added links to the instructions I had found and tried. The first was the official No-IP KB. The second was a post here for Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @NickSillito, thanks for the guide link. Did you setup No-IP with the ddclient as mentioned in the article?

Answer (score 6):

Found this link that worked perfectly: https://www.andreagrandi.it/2014/09/02/configuring-ddclient-to-update-your-dynamic-dns-at-noip-com/

> [noip.com](https://noip.com) is one of the few dynamic DNS free
>   services that are reliable to use. If you have, like in my situation,
>   a Raspberry Pi connected to your home DSL and you want it to be always
>   reachable without knowing the current IP address (the IP could change
>   if you have a normal DSL service at home), you need a dynamic DNS
>   service.
>
> To update the noip.com one you just need ddclient, a tool that is
>   available in Raspbian/Debian repository. You can install it with this
>   command:
>         sudo apt-get install ddclient
>
> then you just need to edit `/etc/ddclient.conf`
>
> ```
> protocol=dyndns2
> ssl=yes
> use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.com/, web-skip='Current IP Address: '  
> server=dynupdate.no-ip.com  
> login=yourusername  
> password=yourpassword  
> yourhostname.no-ip.org
> ```
>
> and restart the client:
>
> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/ddclient restart
> ```
>
> Please remember that noip.com free accounts have a limitation: they
>   need to be confirmed every 30 days (You will receive an email and you
>   need to click on the link contained to update your DNS).

Thanks to @NickSillito for the ddclient tip.